# existe un atajo para hacer lo contrario a TAB en bloques (identacion)

Tags: python, visual-studio, pycharm, atom-editor, sublimetext

pues he estado estudiando python y c++ usando atom y es obstinante que no pueda regresar la identacion por bloques ya que atom tiene muchas cosas automatizadas como las llaves automaticas en bloques me gustaria saber si existe un atajo para regresar una identacion en bloque sin que sea control z eso es deshacer.

y si existe en otros editores me gustaria conocer cuales.

La idea es para hacer mas rapido el proceso de escribir

Comment: En Atom no conozco la respuesta, pero en Visual Studio Code, esto se puede lograr con el shortcut Shift+Tab.

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por sus repuestas.
    he probado y al parecer shift tab funciona en la gran mayoria de editores como atom y notepad++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pulsa mayúscula más tabulación y tendrás el resultado que quieres, es decir **MAYUS+TAB** que es lo contrario a **TAB**.

Como mejores editores de Python te recomiendo PyCharm o VSCode.

Answer (score 2):

Pues si, si el TAB hace la tabulación, lo contrario es hacer `shift + TAB`. Haciendo esto, **quita una tabulación**.